# Big Commerce, Top\Featured\New Products on category page

Tags: bigcommerce

Hi there working with bigcommerce Im looking to get the following style of break down on each category page

Essentially making a category version of;

```
%%Panel.HomeFeaturedProducts%%
%%Panel.SideTopSellers%%
%%Panel.HomeNewProducts%%
```

Ive gone ahead and attempted this however they seem to be pulling in from global values,  and there dose not seem to me much option to break these down or limit the category,  has anyone done this previously and if so how?

Comment: Those panels will not offer contextually unique data. This method will not work. You would need to come up with a more creative / custom code solution.

Answer (score 1):

developerscott is correct in those panels not offering contextually unique data. I'd recommend looking into [Unbxd](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/unbxd-recommendations/). It has a 30 day trial so you can either investigate their programmatic solution or use it in place of making your own.